# Docker node.js Ctrl+C in Node.Js ssh deploy

Tags: bash, ssh, docker

I have a shell script to deploy a docker app, and when I run it, ssh connection is not terminated so I need to force quit the terminal. The app remains running after that.

I've tried nohup, screen and & without success. Is there a way to release the connection gracefully?

```
ssh -tt $host "cd $appname && docker run -p 13370:13370 -ti $appname"
```

Comment: *I've tried nohup, screen* ... how did you try? I see only command without them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '-i' option to 'docker run' keeps STDIN open.  The '-t' option allocates a pseudo tty.

```
-i, --interactive=false         Keep STDIN open even if not attached
-t, --tty=false                 Allocate a pseudo-TTY
```

You will need to tell docker to run your command in the background using '-d' and omit the '-it'.

```
-d, --detach=false              Run container in background and print container ID
```

You should not need the '-tt' to ssh.  Try this:

```
ssh $host "cd $appname && docker run -p 13370:13370 -d $appname"
```

You may also want to specify a restart policy using --restart=always.

```
--restart=no                    Restart policy to apply when a container exits
```